# Child window does not appear on loading (onload) parent window

Tags: javascript

In an html file with php code (intereuropeco1.php) I write:

The prepUnuaLabrp(lg) function is loaded by an inclusion:

In IMW.js, located in the same directory as intereuropeco1.php, I write:

```
function prepUnuaLabrp (lg)
if (lg == "esp") {
    enh='text1';
} else {
    enh='text2';
}
testpagho = window.open ("" , "GT", specif) ;
tekstF = '<HTML><BODY>' + enh + '</BODY></HTML>';
testpagho.document.write(tekstF);
testpagho.document.close();
testpagho.focus();
}
```

But *testpagho* does not appear. (*specific* is defined as
specif = specifB + " , left = " + mldkr + " , width = " + largh + " , scrollbars = 0" with
specifB = "toolbar = 0 , location = 0 , directories = 0 , menubar = 0 , status = 0 , resizable , height = " + alto + ' , top = " + supro ;
and all variables mldkr , largh , alto and supro are properly initialized.)

Comment: What error do you get in the browser?

Comment: When is the function (that is missing the opening curlybrace) triggered? On page load? A popup window can only be opened with a user action, as in clicking something etc. Any other attempt to open a popup will be blocked by the browser

Comment: Good question! I forgot: <body onload="prepUnuaLabrp('esp')">. Will that be blocked?